# mod_rewrite seems to ignore [L] flag

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use the `[L]` flag in `RewriteRule`, but it doesn't seem to work.  I'd like that if you call the page:

```
www.domain.com/admin/
```

it redirects you to:

```
www.domain.com/backend.php
```

Otherwise, if you call any other page (except for some pages) it redirects to:

```
www.domain.com/index.php
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) /backend.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|assets|images|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If I use only the first rule, it works (but obviously doesn't redirect other pages to index.php).  If I add the second rule, the server seems to ignore the first rule (I think it is "overwritten" by the second rule, even if I added the `[L]` flag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how `L` works. The rewrite engine will continually loop through all the rules until the URI going into the engine is the same as the one coming out. The `L` just tells the rewrite engine to stop applying rules *in the current loop iteration*. So say you have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar/$1 [L]
```

after 1 iteration, given the URI `/blah`, I get `/foo/blah` because it stops rewriting after the first rule (but will still continue to loop). If I remove the `L`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar/$1
```

after 1 iteration, given the URI `/blah`, I get `/bar/foo/blah`. Both rules get applied, one after the other because the `L` isn't there to stop it.

You need to add a condition in your second rule to prevent it from rewriting the first, either one of these will do:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(backend\.php|index\.php|admin|assets|images|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

or:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|assets|images|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add backend.php in the condition of the second rule. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your second rule is strange.  I do not know what you are attempting to do by putting `$1` as the value you are checking your condition against.  It should probably look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) /backend.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(index\.php|admin|assets|images|uploads|robots\.txt|backend\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Note I have also added a pass-through for `backend.php`