# Return 410 for all but robots.txt

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a machine I'm leasing that was assigned an IP address that must have previously been assigned to some kind of link spamming company. Said company has hundreds of domains that still resolve to the IP address of my server, and Google and the like are constantly attempting to index the site with their bots (hundreds of thousands of pages). I've been unsuccessful in getting said link spammer to change their DNS records to resolve elsewhere. Fine.

I decided I could use mod_rewrite to deal with this in a fairly direct manner: I want any request that doesn't include one of my domain names to return 410, unless the request is for `/robots.txt`. For the robots file I want to return a simple file that disallows everything with a 200. By my thinking I can quickly extinguish the bots and return to normal.

My mod_rewrite configuration looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*foo\.com$
RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ /robots-off.txt [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*foo\.com$
RewriteRule !^/robots\.txt$ - [G]
```

Where all of the domains I might host on this IP fall somewhere under/at the `foo.com` domain. So I would expect the first rule to tell Apache to output the contents of `/robots-off.txt` with a 200 whenever a request is made for `/robots.txt` for any domain other than my own.

Sadly what's happening is that every request results in a 410, so the bots never get the chance to learn why that they should stop indexing the entire site. Here is the response when I query the wrong host:

```
The requested resource<br />/robots-off.txt<br />
is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address.
Please remove all references to this resource.
```

This has been going on for over a week with no end in sight. The first rule is running, but the [L] seems to be ignored and the second rule is then run. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I misunderstood how [L] works. See here: [mod_rewrite seems to ignore [L] flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319991/mod-rewrite-seems-to-ignore-l-flag)

The working code looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*foo\.com$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots-off.txt [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*foo\.com$
RewriteRule !^robots-off\.txt$ - [L,G]
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but this would return a redirect to the browser, the browser would then re-request robots-off.txt this would be a new request and so again be rewritten. However if you do a pas-through then apache will return the final file inline and so no new request is made and the last is honoured in the way you expect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*foo\.com$

RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots-off.txt [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*foo\.com$

RewriteRule !^robots-off\.txt$ - [L,G]
```