# Apache RewriteRule [L] flag ignored

Tags: apache, http, web, mod-rewrite, server

I'm trying to configure Apache rewrite rules. My website directory contains three files

```
index.html
index2.html
index3.html
```

I'm using these Apache rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule index.html /index2.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule index2.html /index3.html [R=301,L]
```

According to Apache's documentation about the [[L] option](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l):

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.

So when I request `index.html` I would expect `index2.html` to be served. However the request for `index.html` ends up in `index3.html`. Shouldn't the `[L]` option stop the processing of the second `RewriteRule`?

I'm using Apache version is 2.4.39 (Fedora). A similar question [was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319991/mod-rewrite-seems-to-ignore-l-flag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the rules in `.htaccess` are processed on every request. A number actions take place when I access `http://www.example.com/index.html` :

1. .`index.html` is requested
2. The first rule in `.htaccess` is processed. It matches `index.html` and redirects to `index2.html`. `[L]` stops processing subsequent rules
3. `index2.html` is requested
4. The first rule in `.htaccess` is processed. It fails to match `index.html` so the flags `[R=301,L]` are not applied
5. The second rule in `.htaccess` is processed. It matches `index2.html` and redirects to `index3.html`. `[L]` stops processing subsequent rules

I found two possible solutions:

- Move the rewrite rules from `/var/www/html/.htaccess`  to `/etc/httpd/sites-available/example.com.conf`. Unlike `.htaccess` which is processed on every request,  `example.com.conf`  is processed only once -- when the server is started.
- Leave the rules in `.htaccess` but use `[END]` flag instead of `[L]`.

The advantage of the first solution is that the rules are processed only one time.